# random quote machine - changing colors on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, quote

I have been doing one of the challenges in freecodecamp and can get a simple feature to work for some reason and i really have no clue yet.
I want to change the css of some elements on clicks using jQuery (similar to the example site, really loved the idea) but it just doesn't work. Please help..
I have the variable with different colors.

```
var colors = ["#D3FFA3", "#FFF8A7", "#FFBC98", "#FF9A95", "#FFA5FC", "#B7BBFF", "#B6FDFF", "#A8FFC1", "#B6FF99"];

var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  $("body").animate({
    backgroundColor: colors[randomColor],
    color: colors[randomColor]
  }, 500);
```

but it doesnt work, I tried this too:

```
var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var color = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
$("body").animate({backgroundColor: color}, 1000);
```

the only one that worked was this but I'm not sure if I can animate colors using this method

```
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = colors[randomColor];
```

So my question is, can I animate using document.getElementById method and why is jQuery not working? I'm using codepen.io and loaded jquery in the settings (alongside with jQuery UI).

Comment: I believe you need to include jQueryUI to be able to animate background-color. Although it would be much better to do it in CSS instead of JS

Comment: You got 5 answers and you commented on not a single one of those. Was any helpful? Accepting an answer or at least commenting to get more info / guidance  would be nice.

Comment: sorry, im new on SO, gave everyone upvote but looks like i need some reputation for it to count. I tried all of the answers and used the css solution by James Monger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with CSS alone.

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

You can then use your code to change the `background-color`, which will trigger the transition:

```
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = colors[randomColor];
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vcuyq526/)

[Google has information on why you would use CSS vs JS animations](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/animations/css-vs-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this example for changing background color of a div

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').click(function(){
       var back = ["#D3FFA3", "#FFF8A7", "#FFBC98", "#FF9A95", "#FFA5FC", "#B7BBFF", "#B6FDFF", "#A8FFC1", "#B6FF99"];;
       var rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
       console.log(rand);
       $('div').css('background',rand);
    })
})
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sJTHc/278/)

Answer (score 0):

You could animate the backgroundColor with css as well

```
body {
    background-color: #AD310B;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

Just set the backgroundColor with javaScript and it will animate.But I'm not sure if `getElementById("body")` is right. More like `document.querySelector("body")`

```
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = colors[randomColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you cannot animate with plain JQuery, as explained in their docs

> Animation Properties and Values
>
> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used).

See http://api.jquery.com/animate/

For color animations, you can use the [mentioned plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) or something else like like [jQuery UI](https://api.jqueryui.com/color-animation/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('button').click(function(){
  var colors = ["#D3FFA3", "#FFF8A7", "#FFBC98", "#FF9A95", "#FFA5FC", "#B7BBFF", "#B6FDFF", "#A8FFC1", "#B6FF99"];
   var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length) + 0;
    $("body").animate({backgroundColor: colors[randomColor]}, "slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script>
<body>
<button >Click Here</button>
<div class="colorChange">

this will change color 
</div>
</body>
```

Please check code . I think it might help you

thanks